# Extract elements from dynamic list as increases or decreases in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, dynamic

Hello i have a dynamic list which increases or decreases accordingly from the extracted data from a site with BeautifulSoup

```
mylist = [a,b,c,d,.......]
```

how can i make the following fstring to be dynamic as the list increases or decreases?

```
fstr = print(f"the forecast for the week is (choose number): {nl}1. {mylist[0]}{nl}2. {mylist[1]}{nl}3. {mylist[2]}{nl}4. {mylist[3]}{nl}5. Show all week")
```

As you can see i want the elements of mylist to be seperated by \nl in the fstring and not join it to a string.
Is this possible?

the Output is

```
the forecast for the week is (choose number): 
1. Tuesday 08  2022
2. Wednesday 09  2022
3. Thursday 10  2022
4. Friday 11  2022
```

Comment: if you assign the value of the `print("somestring")` function, the value of the string will be `None`

Answer (score 1):

```
myCommaSeparatedValues = ', '.join(myList)
```

This should work, then insert this list into your `fstr` variable:

```
fstr = f"Show the following {myCommaSeparatedValues}"
```

---

NOTE: never call a variable `list` since you are overwriting the built-in class `list`. Call it `myList` instead.

---

In Python to print a newline you have to use the standard `char` `'\n'`.

I assume you have a nested `list` with this structure:

```
myList = [
    ['1', 'Monday', '08', 2022],
    ['2', 'Tuesday', '09', 2022]
]
```

You can print as you expected this way:

```
fstr = "The forecast for the week is (choose number):"
for i in myList:
    fstr += f"\n{' '.join(i)}"
print(fstr)
```

Comment: No i don't want to join the elements of myList to a string but place it into the fstring as seperate.

Comment: So can you provide a sample output in your question?

Comment: the original fstring is fstring = f"the forecast for the week is (choose number): {nl}1. {dates[0]}{nl}2. {dates[1]}{nl}3. {dates[2]}{nl}4. {dates[3]}{nl}5. Show all week"

Comment: The output is the string after the formatting fase... the output that the user reads from the terminal. If possible write it properly formatted in the question.

Comment: As you can see the elements of myList is seperated into the fstring because i want to be in seperate lines

Comment: I have edit properly my question please take a look.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, I'm editing my answer... EDIT: I'll do it after dinner, sorry

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `join` method:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
fstr = f'show this: {', '.join(mylist)}'
```

or you could do this:

```
fstr = f'show this: {str(mylist).removeprefix("[").removesuffix("]")}'
```

output:

```
show this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

to dynamically change the list, you would have a updater function, witch would update the values:

```
def update(values):
    globals()["fstr"] = f'show this: {', '.join(list1+values)}'
```

but is not or you could pass the entire list instead:

```
def update(mylist):
    globals()["fstr"] = f'show this: {', '.join(mylist)}'
```

to update them constantly, you would need a loop, like:

```
while updating:
    ... # updating the values
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first solution is the most pythonic, even thought the second might (I'm not sure at all) be faster. +1

Comment: I have edit properly my question please take a look.